# How would you cache in R2DBC?

Tags: java, caching, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am trying to implement something like this [Spring boot populating cache used by findById method with findAll method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664404/spring-boot-populating-cache-used-by-findbyid-method-with-findall-method)

but with R2DBC.  However, it does not appear to work as I am returning a Mono.

```java
@Cacheable("stores",key = "#storeId")
Mono<Store> findById(int storeId);
```

The way I determine it is looking at the general_log of the database and find that it's still performing the query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with there being any fluent integration between the @Cacheable annotation and reactive frameworks. The primary issue is that there are no non-blocking cache implementations (JSR-107 cache API is blocking). Only Redis is providing a reactive driver. [See Spring.io's reactive caching guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-data-reactive-redis/). I've read somewhere that you can still use the annotation on service methods, but that will "only" cache your wrapper objects, i.e., Mono / Flux, but not the actual result of your findById..